# MobileFirst could not view the worklight console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have done the following

```
(1) Installed WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.6 
(2) Installed MySQL and JDK 1.7
(3) customisation of configuration-liberty-mysql.xml with my settings
(4) ant -f myxmlfile admdatabases
(5) ant -f myxmlfile adminstall
(6) ant -f myxmlfile databases
(7) ant -f myxmlfile install
```

and when I try to view the console 'localhost:8080/worklightconsole' I get the error

```
**'Service unavailable since initialization is not yet complete'**
```

and each time I start the server using the option '--clean'

Paste Bin URL's

http://pastebin.com/DPR35HwA   (for messages.log)
http://pastebin.com/JSTY7gtm   (for server.xml)

As I am new to MobileFirst I hope I am missing something.  Help me to fix

Thanks
Sathish Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the MySQL library is wrong in the server.xml file. In the jdbcDriver element you reference the library "worklightconsole/MySQLLib". But in your library element the id is MySQLLib.

So change one of the elements in order the references match (for example libraryRef="MySQLLib").

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   Despite changing that I see the error in messages.log  "FWLSE0204E: MobileFirst Server cannot be started because no data-source is bound to resource reference: 'jdbc/WorklightDS'. Re-configuring the server will solve this problem."   any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You have many other errors. For example for the MFP runtime the application id and name are not correct: application id="worklightconsole" name="worklightconsole" location="renamedclsapp.war" type="war". You use the same id/name than the console.

Comment: Yes I rectified that error related to named conflict

Comment: After spending sometime I get 'timeout error'

http://pastebin.com/iYUjpkSQ
http://pastebin.com/fcxUKjGL

FWLSE0242E: Failed to synchronize application runtime information. The servlet initialization failed and the servlet will deny service due to a failure to communicate with the worklightadmin service. Common reasons are that the worklightadmin service is not started correctly or that the ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid property has not the same value for the worklightadmin service and the runtime

Please help me to fix this 'timeout issue'